# AWS , Spring Boot, Tomcat : Session replication

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a `spring boot application` which uses `embedded tomcat`. The app is hosted on multiple `EC2` instances, which auto scale if required and some of which may be killed/restarted. So, effectively there are 3 instances of the app running , and requests are routed from the load balancer to any of these instances.

I am trying to `track user sessions` on my app. I started with implementing container level session management using tomcat `HttpSession`. But it is not able to track sessions across instances. On researching a bit, I got to know that i need something like session replication.

My app is not running a tomcat cluster, it has 3 independent instances of the API which do not talk to each other in anyway. I am not planning to change that and not sure if it is possible with `AWS` as it does not encourage multicast communication for this purpose.

Also, I do not want to setup/manage a separate DB (like `redis with spring session`) just for this purpose, because I only need `session Ids` for logging, and I need to do that in a lightweight manner.

Is there any other way to manage sessions across instances ? or for my purpose, would it be better to just implement some custom code which can check for session id/token passed to and fro between the frontend and backend.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to externalize the sessions from your application server so that you can autoscale, restart, load balance etc. without worrying about breaking a User's session.

Honestly on AWS using the Spring stack, I would recommend [Spring Session + Redis](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html).  I've used it countless times and it is very easy to implement.  You can leverage [AWS Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) which manages the Redis cluster for you (like RDS does for relational DBs).

You could write your own custom implementation of Spring Session with a backing store of S3, Dynamo, etc.  But is that really any better than the Redis implementation?  I'd recommend the path of least resistance.

Comment: How about using tomcat clustering which is cost effective ?